# How to order array multidimensional of collections by value?

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I have this array of objects below, however, note that it follows a line based on the `id` field at a given time and I'm not sure why, it changes that form and from Id 8 it goes to 19, however there is the 13, 14, 15 that he adds at the end.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [id_pai] => [id_patrocinador] => [id_usuario] => 1 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [id_pai] => 1 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 93 [ordem] => 2 [lado] => D [created_at] => [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [id_pai] => 1 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 94 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 19:26:17 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [id_pai] => 1 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 95 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 19:28:00 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [2] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [id_pai] => 93 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 96 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:13:30 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [id_pai] => 93 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 97 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:15:54 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8 [id_pai] => 93 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 98 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:16:41 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [3] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 15 [id_pai] => 96 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 105 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:11 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 16 [id_pai] => 96 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 106 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:14 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 17 [id_pai] => 96 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 107 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:16 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [4] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 76 [id_pai] => 105 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 114 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-22 04:27:18 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [5] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 18 [id_pai] => 97 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 108 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:19 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [id_pai] => 97 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 109 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:22 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 20 [id_pai] => 97 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 110 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:25 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [6] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [id_pai] => 98 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 111 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:27 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [id_pai] => 98 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 112 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:31 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 23 [id_pai] => 98 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 113 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:21:33 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [7] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 9 [id_pai] => 94 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 99 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:19:59 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [id_pai] => 94 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 100 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:20:10 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 [id_pai] => 94 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 101 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:20:12 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) [8] => Illuminate\\Support\\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [id_pai] => 95 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 102 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:20:15 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13 [id_pai] => 95 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 103 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:20:18 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 [id_pai] => 95 [id_patrocinador] => 1 [id_usuario] => 104 [ordem] => [lado] => [created_at] => 2019-01-21 20:20:20 [updated_at] => [deleted_at] => ) ) ) )
```

How could I do to sort this structure in order to walk based on the `id` field, or better still, the field `id_usuario` without losing the consistency sequential?

Comment: convert your object to array, then `usort` would be your friend

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: something like this: `usort(json_decode(json_encode($object), true), function($a, $b){return $a['id_usuario' > $b['id_usuario']});`